# Unable to implement recaptcha gem options in a Rails 4.2 app

Tags: recaptcha, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using the [recaptcha gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) version 4.0, and therefore placed `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` inside a form. There are options that you are supposed to be able to implement  to change the size (normal or compact?) and theme (light or dark).

I reviewed numerous posts here and elsewhere without finding a syntax that works. Here are several options I used based on what I found:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags :display => {:size => 'compact', :theme => 'dark'} %>
<%= recaptcha_tags :display => {size: 'compact', theme: 'dark'} %>
<%= recaptcha_tags :size => 'compact'} %>
<%= recaptcha_tags size: 'compact'} %>
```

Nove of these worked. I also removed the options from the recaptcha tags and modified the gem's client_helper.rb file. I cut all of the width and height styles were cut in half. That didn't work either. I'd rather use the options that can be supplied in the recaptcha tags. Anybody know how to do that? Thanks in advance! Jay

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

check the generated tag, if you pass `size: 'compact'` it should create a `data-size="compact"` attribute
https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/client_helper.rb#L70-L71

if that does not work, update to latest ... maybe `bundle open recaptcha` ... if size should not be data-size but regular size then this might be a bug and needs a proper fix ... still open the gem, turn it remove `:size` from the list and see if that fixes it

--retransmitted from grosser